# overclock atom n2800 CPU

Tags: cpu, overclocking, intel-atom

I have a netbook (EeePC 1025C) with atom n2800 1.86GHZ CPU. I tried to use SETFSB to overclock, but I can't find the required 9LPRS432AGLF clock generator. In the BIOS there is no overclock option neither.

In this case, is there any method to overclock this CPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: There is currently no way to overclock an n2800.

I asked the SETFSB people whether they would support the 1025C and the 9LPRS432AGLF and they 
replied with a simple "No". I also asked IDT for a data sheet on the clock generator but they refused, saying it is proprietary for Asus. Asus refused to provide the data sheet.